# Excel file to PDF File

Tags: asp.net, excel, pdf

Hi I'm trying to Convert my Excel file with textbox and rectangle object to PDF File, I tried to use Spire.Xls but error encountered during conversion XML error then when I tried GemBox textbox and rectangle not showing on PDF then when I tired Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel not converting properly Thanks in advance

Comment: If that rectangle that you mentioned was a shape, note that those elements previously were not supported by GemBox.Spreadsheet API. However, the latest versions do have support for `Shape` elements, see [Excel Shapes](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/excel-shapes/211) example .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, 
File 
Save As
Save as type (down at the drop-down)
and *.pdf

For me that converts the textbox and the triangle as well.

Put it on a single button and works for me with referencing:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"H:\My Documents\Fun\tri.xlsx");
            xlWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, @"H:\My Documents\Fun\tri.pdf");
```

Comment: Hi @Anna want to convert excel file with textbox and rectangle object to pdf in C# program not manual

Answer (score 0):

You copy paste the below method,

```
private bool ConvertToPDF(string sourcePath, string targetPath, XlFixedFormatType targetType)
    {
        bool result;
        object missing = Type.Missing;
        ApplicationClass application = null;
        Workbook workBook = null;
        try
        {
            application = new ApplicationClass();
            object target = targetPath;
            object type = targetType;
            workBook = application.Workbooks.Open(sourcePath, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
                               missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
            workBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(targetType, target, XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, true, false, missing, missing, missing, missing);
            result = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            result = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (workBook != null)
            {
                workBook.Close(true, missing, missing);
                workBook = null;
            }
            if (application != null)
            {
                application.Quit();
                application = null;
            }
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
        return result;

    }
```

Add the Reference as "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" and after adding this,  Right click the "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" and select properties, and change "Embed Interop Types" to false

And you can call the method as like below

```
ConvertToPDF(@"D:\WithImage_Shapes.xlsx", @"D:\WithImage_Shapes.pdf", XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF);
```

You can get the result what you expected.

If my answer fills yours expectation, Kindly upward the answer and click the Green Tick.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Spire.XLS but it converted successfully?
My code:

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
workbook.LoadFromFile(@"aa.xlsx");

Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

sheet.SaveToPdf("ToPDF.pdf");
```

PDF file:
[image]